# styled components silently failing when passing a string to linear-gradient

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I am passing the following string to my Styles as a prop:

```
let colorsString = "#48b500, #FFFF00, #f52700"
<LegendStyle colors={colorsString}>
  <div className='map-gradient'></div>
</LegendStyle>
```

Then I have a definition like this:

```
const LegendStyle = s.div `
  .map-gradient {
    height: 100px;
    width: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(${props => props.colors});
 }
`
```

But the background styles do not get applied to my `.map-gradient` div

This is the styles in the chrome inspector after render:

```
.efZtAp .map-gradient {
    height: 100px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Figured it out, I was missing a curly brace at the end of my style definitions...

Comment: Edited the question, currently only the background colors are not getting applied to my div

Comment: I am now thinking that the problem could be the quotes surrounding my string?

Comment: What if you add a direction, i.e. _to bottom_ `linear-gradient(to bottom, ${props => props.colors})` ... and how does the rendered code look like?

Comment: to bottom does not solve the issue. I also edited the question with the styles in chrome inspector. The DOM renders as expected.

Comment: How does the div render as expected? .. it doesn't have the background property

Comment: What I meant was that the DOM renders as expected, while the styles do not get applied. I found the issue, it was another typo. Will close the question, thanks for all the help